# Bypass Window Closing Event From Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a child window with a closing event to prevent any accidental closure.  In this child window I have a button click handler that will perform an operation then close the child and report to the parent window about new info.  Unfortunately, this button action also calls the closing event.  How can I bypass this specific window closing event and just report said info?

I just read that over and it seems a bit confusing.  I'll edit if need be.

Comment: It seems there were a lot of different solutions to this problem and I pretty much just implemented the first one I saw that worked.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you set in OnClosing the `Cancel`-property to `true` and therefore the window does not close. Now you look for a possibilty to close the window from your button click event although you have this OnClosing-event. Right?
A possibility is to define a member variable which you set in the buttons event. In the OnClosing you only set e.Cancel to true, if this member variable is not set.

```
class YourClass{
    bool m_closeAnyway;
    void OnClosing(....){
         if(!m_closeAnyway){
             e.Cancel=true;
         }
    }
    void ButtonClickEventHandler(...){
        m_closeAnyway=true;
        Close();
        DoTheRest();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should review your design.

You could do something like that:

```
public void ClosingEvent (...)
{
    if(this.ToValidate)
    {
        this.Validate();
        // Or e.Cancel; I don't know exactly know what you want to prevent...
    }
}

public void ButtonClick(...)
{
   this.ToValidate = false;
   this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a property like ForceClosed defaulted to true and on the button click set to to be false.  When the close event fires, check to see if ForceClosed is true.  If so then perform whatever is needed to prevent accidental closure.